# GridDB Java not found error when calling gs_sh on windows subsystem for linux (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I've followed [the instructions](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/wsl/#running-griddb-on-wsl) to install GridDB on Windows Subsystem for Linux. While the install seems to have gone successfully, I'm having an issue getting into the GridDB CLI.

The official instructions for WSL were not entirely clear how to use GridDB CLI - the hyperlink just redirected to the page I was already looking at. But I found the following instructions and was [following them](https://github.com/griddb/cli/blob/main/Specification_en.md)

So I did the following:

```
/usr/bin$ gs_sh
/usr/bin/gs_sh: 40: java: not found
```

I've looked through the instructions with no mention of this error. Any ideas?